# Python Best Practice: Better to use nested functions or private function syntax?

Tags: python

I made a package that I've refactored following Uncle Bob's clean code book.

The result: I have a ton of smaller functions from the giant functions I had before (as I'm still learning Python & best practices).

My question is this:

**To keep things organized...**

**On functions you won't use other places...**

is it better to use nested functions

```
def public_func():
    def private_func():
        # do abc
    private_func()
    # do xyz
```

or have a lot of smaller functions with the private function syntax?

```
def _private_func():
   # do abc

def public_func():
   _private_func()
   # do xyz
```

Comment: *Probably* the latter, since it does not involve redefining `private_func` every time `public_func` is called. The nested function is useful if it closes over some other variable local to `public_func`.

Comment: IMO, a `nested` function looks a bit convoluted. Better to have smaller functions.

Comment: As far as I know, no Python implementation performs [lambda lifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_lifting), so the first version induces an unavoidable runtime cost that the second does not.

Comment: Just to mention that "private" is not really correct term. And depending on what these functions do it may be better to organise them as methods in a class.

Comment: @chepner That was another question I had. I just couldn't find where the best practice was on keeping these organized in pep8 as well haha. Should you even use the private name syntax (_name) at all in module functions or just have them just be normal smaller functions that are only used once?

Comment: If the function is *really* intended only as an implementation detail of another function, I would use `_name`. However, I would give hard thought to whether the function *could* be useful elsewhere, even if you don't currently do so. Also, every function call adds overhead to the total runtime, so consider whether you really need the private function, especially if it gets called in a loop.

Comment: If you don't *mean* to create a new function on each invocation of the outer function *then don't beat it*, that's confusing

Answer (score 5):

As the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says:

> Flat is better than nested.

But also:

> Simple is better than complex.
> Complex is better than complicated.

Therefore, try to not use nested, but if it makes it more complicated, keep it simple.